solving large amount (1 million) of individual small nonlinear systems of equations using JAX
I have some technical inquiries regarding the capabilities of JAX in addressing a substantial number (1 million) of individual small nonlinear systems of equations. Currently, my approach involves distributing these jobs across 200 CPUs using MPI, where each CPU sequentially resolves 5,000 individual nonlinear systems. This process necessitates differentiation and the use of a linear algebra solver.
After reviewing the JAX documentation, I would like to clarify the following points:
(1) JAX appears to be efficient for solving a single nonlinear system of equations using automatic differentiation and jax.numpy. However, when it comes to processing 1 million individual jobs, what is the recommended method for parallel execution? My understanding is that GPUs and TPUs primarily enhance the performance of individual tasks rather than multiple concurrent jobs.
(2) Given that the dimensionality of the nonlinear systems is under 100, how does JAX's performance compare to that of NumPy for these smaller problems? Is JAX's advantage primarily evident in higher-dimensional scenarios?
I appreciate any insights you can provide. Thank you.
Update:
My code consists of multiple functions and modules designed to solve a PDE, so it's not something that can be condensed into just a few lines. The general workflow is as follows,
n  = 1000000
m  = 100
y  =  jnp.zeros((n, m))

for i in jnp.arange(1,n):
    y = y.at[i, :].set(jnp.linalg.solve(A, b))

where A and b are computed from other functions. The inputs for A and b across n iterations come from a single large dataset indexed by i, but the calculation of A and b are independent for each iteration. It seems that 'prange' of numba can parallelize the for loop. I don't know if JAX offers similar functionality.
I also tested MPI4JAX, where the for loop is distributed across 10 CPU cores, achieving a 10x speed-up. With MPI-type parallelization, computation time decreases linearly as more cores are added. However, the number of CPU cores is limited to 100 for my workstation, meaning each core still has to process 10,000 iterations sequentially. Since GPUs have far more CUDA cores, I expect that using a GPU could potentially perform the job much faster.

are you constrained to using jax? can you edit the question to be a minimal reproducible example?

I think JAX would not be a solution for my problem after communicating with others. mpi4py is the way to go.

Well, if you share code of the equation you're solving / how you're solving it others may be able to offer better solutions. For instance, if it can be solved using fsolve or leastsq, then you can use cminpack_numba which, I wrote when faced with this issue, and is likely very fast and can easily be run in parallel within numba, but I can't time it on your problem

@Nin17 I have updated the post. Thanks for your comments.

The code shows you're solving a linear system of equations?

Yes. The final step is solving a linear system. A is Jacobian matrix computed by autodiff.

I think you'll need to share more code if you want any useful advice - can you upload how you're solving a single problem? At the minute the question is basically unanswerable as there are no testable details of what you're doing. Like I said I've also faced similar issues where JAX solves a single non-linear problem quickly but it is difficult to make it fast if there are many similar problems to solve so I resorted to numba.
